# Using select2 with multiple choices and duplicate id values

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

What I am trying to achieve is using a select2 (version 4.0.0-rc.2) with multiple options to choose the same item multiple times, so basically duplicate choosing of options/ids.

For example I have the data:

`[{'id': 1, 'text': 'A'},{'id': 2, 'text': 'B'},{'id': 3, 'text': 'C'}]`

Currently I am only allowed to select each of these options once.
So if I choose B (with id 2) I can not choose B again.

I would like to be able to choose the following list; `A, C, B, C, B, A` which should result in array or string with the ids `1, 3, 2, 3, 2, 1`

According to this page: https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/1002 that should be possible. However I cannot find it anywhere in the documentation.

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eL7q2y14/1/

Comment: Have you found a solution to this?

Comment: @jpaoletti Unfortunately not.